# Clean redundant files

Tags: makefile, fastq

Well i have a pipeline which runs some data for me with the help of a makefile.
This pipeline creates an enormous amount of redundant files which i want to clean.

I have 1 makefile to run the pipeline. And the pipeline itself is connected to much other makefiles. so i added this code to the pipeline chipcap.mk file:

```
.PHONY cleanintermediate    
cleanintermediate: $(CHIPCAP_OUTPUT)
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE)clipsync.trimsync.fastq
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE)clipsync.fastq
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE)clip.fastq
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE).fastq
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE).wig && $(RM) -rf $(SAMPLE).wig.idx
        rm -rf $(SAMPLE).sam
```

Now i run my file like this `make -f run_samples.mk`
This script will invoke the pipeline and start running all samples separately the command that run_samples.mk gives to the pipeline is:

```
all: pool1_negCTRL pool1R2R1 pool1SP1 pool2Posctrl pool2R2R2 pool2Input

getCommand = $(MAKE) -f /data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/pipelines/chipcap/chipcap.mk \
        IN_DIR=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/input/$(1) \
        OUT_DIR=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/runs/$(2) \
        CHIPCAP_VER=0.1.2 \
        FASTQ_EXT=fastq \
        CHIPCAP_INPUT=$(3) \
        CHIPCAP_QC_MODE=cliptrim \
        GZIP_EXT=gz \
        MACS14_EXE=/home/sajvanderzeeuw/.virtualenvs/ronald/bin/macs \
        PYTHON_EXE=/home/sajvanderzeeuw/.virtualenvs/ronald/bin/python2.7 \
        OPT_MACS14_mfold=$(4),$(5)
        #OPT_MACS14_control=control.bam

#Negative control sample
pool1_negCTRL:
        $(call getCommand,pool1,pool1_negCTRL_monday_test,pool1-negCTRL_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz,15,30)
```

How can i say to run_samples.mk that also cleanintermediate(which is in chipcap.mk) should be executed. I've been puzzling a lot but cant find the right way to do it.

Comment: Is getCommand just running the default target in chipchap.mk? (That's what it looks like but I'm just making sure.) If the default target has a name you might be able to just add `<default target name> cleanintermediate` to the getCommand command and have it work. If not you can also run make a second time in the `pool1_negCTRL` body without all the variables and with `cleanintermediate` as the target.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yess indeed that is what getcommand is doing. (sorry for late reply!) And i think i will manage to get in running by youre explanation thanks for that! if i get it working you will hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cleanintermediate: $(CHIPCAP_OUTPUT)
```

in chipcap.mk should become `cleanintermediate: all`

In runchipcap.mk add cleanintermediate to getCommand

```
getCommand = $(MAKE) -f /data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/pipelines/chipcap/chipcap.mk \
        IN_DIR=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/input/$(1) \
        OUT_DIR=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/runs/$(2) \
        CHIPCAP_VER=0.1.2 \
        FASTQ_EXT=fastq \
        CHIPCAP_INPUT=$(3) \
        CHIPCAP_QC_MODE=cliptrim \
        GZIP_EXT=gz \
        MACS14_EXE=/home/sajvanderzeeuw/.virtualenvs/ronald/bin/macs \
        PYTHON_EXE=/home/sajvanderzeeuw/.virtualenvs/ronald/bin/python2.7 \
        OPT_MACS14_mfold=$(4),$(5) cleanintermediate
        #OPT_MACS14_control=control.bam
```